# Android Authentication and GCM Push notifications

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm looking to create for my app some authentication. This will basically consist of a user registering (preferably with their google account, although not necessary) and providing a username that is then sent to my server and then having the ability to log in. I then from there would like to be able for the client app to communicate with my server by sending data and receiving push notifications via GCM (google cloud messaging). It is important that the server is able to send a push notification directly to a certain user not to all registered devices.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction for what I must do? I've had a look at a few tutorials but what I've seen has always sent messages to all registered devices not to a specific user.

Some extra information about the app:
-The client app (user) will need to send a piece of information to the server. This information will also include the user that it needs to be sent to. Once the server receives the piece of information it should send a push notification through GCM to the specified user's client app.

I'm clueless as to how I need to go about setting up the authentication system, any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offcourse you can send push notifications to selected users. This process would roughly comprise the following steps:

1) send the User's GCM registration id to your own server along with a unique user id (what ever id you have assigned to that user; could be email or sim id or something like that). Save it in your database.

2) To send Push notifications to selected users, choose users from the database based on some criteria, retrieve their GCM registration ids from the database and forward them the GCM server.

but there is one important thing you must handle. GCM registration ids could change e.g if user uninstalls and re-installs the application. You must update you corresponding database entry in that case.

Comment: Fantastic. Would it be a good idea to update the registration ID in the database on every login the user performs? I assume that I am able to make the GCM register once they are logged in, fetch the registration ID and push it to the server?

On top of this, are you aware of any suitable tutorials that can assist me with creating an authentication system?

Thank you very much once again!

Comment: I dont think you should be performing registration every time the user logs in. GCM would send you failures if the reg id has changed. It would be better to update the database only then, if you can afford the lag. You can find a good example on implementing GCM client here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and for server here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

Comment: I would wouldn't I? Because what if they log out and log in as a different user, then that user would have the same registration ID but be linked to the wrong user. Also what I'm more concerned with is the actual authentication part. I'm not too sure how I'd make it log in then have a token then it uses to fetch and push data.

Comment: Let me understand, the GCM (now Firebase) token identifies the "device+application", the unique user id (as you said it could be the username or email) identifies the user that is logged in the application.
Then, when we send the notification to the GCM (Firebase) server to that token, we must provide also the user id, then the app must check if the userid correspond to the logged one and show it? And what about if the app is stopped and the notification is handled by the google services on the phone?